# How to allow for many log renderers but customize the rendering per renderer?

Tags: logging, terminal, architecture

This is a language-agnostic question, I am working on a custom programming language and been trying to figure out how to print the errors in the terminal. I want to allow the functionality for errors and for general logging, to customize the rendering in bulk. So basically, for any error you will log it as JSON, or as XML or with ANSI colors, or with ANSI colors in some custom tree layout, etc., similar to how in Mocha.js there are a [number of "reporters"](https://mochajs.org/#reporters), so you can visualize your unit test results/output in a dozen+ different styles. With mocha it's more straightforward because the tests all have the same properties overall. But in my case there could be error types with various different sets of properties, so it's not as straightforward as you might first imagine.

Say we have these error types:

```
type Error = {
  message: string
}

type SyntaxError = Error & {
  filePath: string
  textHighlightRange: {
    start: number
    end: number
  }
}

type TypeError = Error & {
  expectedType: string
  providedType: string
}

// and a dozen other types
```

I would like to display the fields in a particular order, in a particular layout.

A "type error" for our minimal data renderer might look like:

```
There was a type mismatch in the code

expectedType: <Foo>
providedType: <Bar>
stackTrace:
  ./x
  ./y
  ./z
```

A "syntax error" for that renderer might look like:

```
There was a syntax error somewhere in the code

file: ./foo/bar.xyz:12:42
text:
  |
  | var x = 10
  | var y =
  | ~~~~~~~
  |
stackTrace:
  ./x
  ./y
  ./z
```

But then another renderer might want to organize the fields differently, in a different order for making things visually pop in a different way. Etc..

So it's possible to automatically convert every error to JSON, and to XML perhaps, but the order of the fields is what is important when rendering, and the padding.

I guess I could have a DSL for defining a general default layout for arbitrary unknown properties, and then specify a DSL per error type, to say what order the properties go in, and the spacing in between.

```
set file, from filePath
set text, from textHighlightRange
  nested true
space
set stackTrace, nested true
```

And then each "reporter" would read this DSL to figure out how to organize the fields. Otherwise you would have to specify the order of each fields for each reporter. But this might breakdown too, where in XML you don't want any `space`, but in the ANSI one you do.... So then I keep coming back to maybe you'd have to define how to layout each error in each renderer style, with a default fallback. That would be unrealistic though, having a few hundred errors generated by a few dozen packages, you'd have to write 1000 DSLs to customize each case, and just for 1 renderer style!

So is there a better way? How should I think about this to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I haven't written something like this before. This seems like an area to defer and externalize from the language. You seem to have ideas about what information to provide about user issues. Presumably devs working with the language would be working in files and some kind of modules or the like. An abstraction could be used for providing a common set of error data in a digestible format across error types, and perhaps create a tool to default to standard output for example. Ultimately, let external systems handle what rendering means, just provide a way for a them to retrieve/receive the data.